# Measure Theory, Game of Craps.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am looking to define a sigma algebra which can describe the game of craps. In the game 2 fair 6-sided dice are rolled and if a player gets a sum of 7 or 11, then he wins. But if he gets 2,3 or 12, then he loses. If he gets anything other than 2,3,7,11 or 12, then that is recorded as a "point". Then on subsequent rolls, if he gets the "point" again before rolling out a sum of 7, then he wins. But if he rolls out a 7 before the "point" then he loses.

So now I know sample space={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}. I need to define a sigma algebra which can describe the game. Now firstly I thought of making a power set of sample space. But question asks me define a sigma algebra which describes the game. So, I am not so sure about that. If anyone can guide with that, I'll be grateful.

Comment: For a finite set of events, the sigma algebra is just the algebra consisting of all subsets of events.

Comment: But do I need whole power set as a sigma algebra to describe the game?

Comment: Since the individual events must be in the algebra and by definition all countable unions and intersections are in it, you have no choice.

Comment: I took it to be the power set of the sample space and it worked. Thank you so much for help.